# How to detect what media query is active with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to use different views for my platform on mobile devices depending on page orientation (portrait vs landscape).

Is there a way how this could work:

```
<div class="row item-list-video">
  <% for program in @programs %>
    <% if (stylesheet_link_tag "global", :media => "only screen and (max-width: 990px)") %>
      <%= render partial: 'program_preview_landscape',locals: { program: program}  %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render partial: 'program_preview',locals: { program: program} %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I am not sure about how this part is working:

`if (stylesheet_link_tag "global", :media => "only screen and (max-width: 990px)")`

My thoughts were that stylesheet_link_tag is the file name of the .css where the media queries are defined. But what I get is:

> `Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production.
>   Add Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( global.css ) to config/initializers/assets.rb and restart your server`

The program_preview_landscape loads this code:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-3 program-thumbnail-landscape">
  <a href="/shows/<%= program.slug %>">
    <img src="<%= program.thumbnail_uri %>">
  </a>
</div>
```

While the program_preview loads this:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 program-thumbnail">
  <a href="/shows/<%= program.slug %>">
    <img src="<%= program.thumbnail_uri %>">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: That logic should go into your (s)css, not in Rails.

Comment: what logic do you mean? can you give me a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

You can't read the media query from an ERB, because the media width is only calculated in the browser after the HTML is delivered, and by then the ERB has already been rendered. The usual approach to this sort of thing is to have your ERB generate HTML with [semantic markup](https://html.com/semantic-markup/) — the **same** HTML for both desktop and mobile — and then use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to apply different styles depending on the screen width.